# Using google apps-script to disable and enable Form controls based user input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form used for voting / survey.  I would like to enable or disable subsequent controls on this form based on user input.  For example, if a user selects a particular multiple choice item on a current item, I would like to be able to enable or disable some of the subsequent questions based on said prior selection using a script.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use go to sections based om answer?

Comment: Google Forms are not dynamic on the client side even with Google Apps Script. All of the Apps Script functions for Google Forms are server side and the form is filled out client side.  Your options are to either, as @JamesDonnellan suggested, make a form with multiple pages where the response to one question leads to a different page, or use either a stand alone Google Apps Script or one embedded in a spreadsheet to generate the form via HTML Services and manipulate it i the client side and then save the responses to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Let me add a link to an example mock presidential election form to better explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: Let me add a link to an example mock presidential election form to better explain what I am trying to do.   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd86VrSqe6X8EO8CLRGGfQanM1wzx0NkO_zqWXqX7Lclw8RbA/viewform?usp=sf_link   go the form and observe that  I only want to limit the user's ability to write in a candidate if a name has already been picked in the previous question.  In other words, I am trying to keep the user from both selection a candidate in the first question then proceeding to write in  a name.